# How to log aiojobs exceptions to file

Tags: aiohttp

For aiohttp, I can use `logging.getLogger('aiohttp')`, but what to use for `aiojobs`?

My code raised an exception and I noted it in console:

```
Job processing failed
job: <Job coro=<<coroutine object Message.process_messages at 0x108b32150>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to use `logging.getLogger('asyncio')`